# JQuery function to track state and not open class

Tags: jquery, html, class, popup, toggle

I am trying to write a function that does now allow more than one pop up to appear at a time. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
// Click for full bio
$('.div').click(function() {

if('.popup'.!open)             // if popup NOT open, then do this..

$(this).find('.popup').toggle(); 
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create a flag somewhere to track the state.

This example won't work if you copy it, but it should give you a clear idea of what you need to do...

```
var isPopupOpen = false;

$('.toggleLink').click(function() {
    if(!isPopupOpen){
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
        isPopupOpen = true;
    }
});

//this is the bit that don't work, as I don't know what methods you have to be able to detect when it closes
$('.popup').onClose(function() {
    isPopupOpen = false;
});
```